# How can I create a List with sorted Strings and a specific Integer in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

Hay there,
I need to create a list for a project with *amount* of terms for this method but it kind of didn't work as I thought.
The "term"-names also have to look like this and have been sorted in the form of "Term:1", "Term:2",..., "Term:amount". If *amount* should be negative I have to return an empty list.
I tried the following:

```
public static List <String> createTerms(int amount){
List <String> termNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (amount>0){
        termNames.add(amount,"Term:"+amount);
        Collections.sort(termNames);
        return termNames;
    }else
        return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is tagged as JavaScript, this looks like Java. Take a look at the `ArrayList` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Here is the method for `add()`:

```
add(int index, E element)
```

Where it adds `element` to the structure at `index`. So it doesn't work the way you assumed in your code. If you would like to use `ArrayList`, even though I would advise against and suggest you use something like `Map`, found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), I would suggest you use a for-loop to add the terms in. So instead of:

```
 termNames.add(amount,"Term:");
 Collections.sort(termNames);
```

You can just do:

```
  if (amount > 0){
      for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
          String element = "Term: " + (i + 1);
          termNames.add(element);
      } 
      return termNames;
  }
```

Also, I am a bit confused about your logic. Shouldn't the prompt be that you should return an empty list if `amount < 0`? Can you clarify a bit if my answer doesn't answer your question?

Comment: Hello Sam, 
thank you very much for your answer! The prompt should return an empty list if the amount was < 0! I misstyped there (already edited it)
Your answer did solve my question :) I am still not too fond of lists and maps, but I am really greatful for the answer. Especially the part with 
String element = "Term: " + (i + 1);

So thanks again and have an especially nice day!

Comment: The `if (amount > 0)` check is unnecessary. Since the loop’s condition is `i < amount` and the initial value of `i` is zero, the desired behavior of producing an empty list for zero and negative amounts is already implied.

Answer (score 0):

termNames will only ever have 1 element since the list is declared within the scope of the function. You should consider another data structure such as a dictionary for this implementation and make sure it's a global variable if you intend to fill it with more than 1 element

Edit: You should change to tag from Javascript to Java to ensure you receive correct advice

Comment: Thank you for the advice :) And I changed the tag